# Difference between a list and multiset in C++

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, stl, multiset

In C++:

- A list is a collection that can contain non-unique values in sequence
- A multiset is a collection that can contain non-unique elements in sequence

What then is the specific difference between the two? Why would I use on over the other?

I've tried finding this information online but most references (e.g. cplusplus.com) talk about the two containers in different ways, such that the difference is not apparent.

Comment: std::multiset is sorted

Comment: In life bicycle is a device that has wheels and a car is a device that has wheels. I cannot find article that would describe specific difference btw these two :(

Comment: @Slava, the difference will be how many persons would use it. :)

Comment: Did these descriptions come from something you're reading? If so, read on. They are fundamentally different, and any good descriptive text will tell you what they're used for.

Comment: @PeteBecker The descriptions came from my summary of the related cplusplus.com descriptions. The pages obviously go on to list attributes and methods but aside from particular use-cases (which I do not yet have) it does not inform my understanding of the difference. The more descriptive texts I've come across so far online do not appear to realise that they describe the two as the same thing just with different words... any suggestions (comments!) on good sources on this would be welcome

Comment: @Slava Here you go ;) https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-bikes-and-private-cars (someone was polite enough to answer such a question without being condescending)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset):

> `std::multiset` is an associative container that contains a **sorted**
>   set of objects
>
> Search, insertion, and removal operations have logarithmic complexity.

From [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list):

> `std::list` is a container that supports **constant time** insertion and removal of elements from anywhere in the container
>
> Fast random access is **not** supported

Thus, if you want to have a *faster search*, use `multiset`.

For *faster insertion and removal*: use `list`.

Comment: Don't just jump on `list` "for faster insert" -- for _many_ use cases it's just _not better_.  See:  https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists

Comment: It's worth noting that fast insertion into a list assumes an iterator to the position of insertion is already available. Otherwise, finding that iterator may have worse than constant time complexity.

Comment: @Chad, true it may not be better. thanks for sharing. just wanted to point out that an insert would need the iterator position for list.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thank you for pointing out the worst time complexity for list. I totally agree with you.

Comment: `std::vector` usually beats `std::list` on modern hardware for all operations - regardless of theoretical big O complexity.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, true. would be happy to include it if OP asks for it. :)

Answer (score 5):

The biggest difference is `std::list` is a linked list while `std::multiset` is a tree structure (typically an RB Tree).  This means element access in a `std::list` has `O(N)` access while a `std::multiset` has `O(logN)`.

This also means iterating a `std::multiset` from `begin()` to `end()` will give you sorted data while iterating a `std::list` will give you the order the data was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that straightforward, but to be short:
If you need to query search by value many times, opt for `std::multiset.`
Otherwise `std::list`.

Comment: But `std::set` contains unique objects where `std::multiset` does not.

Comment: "Otherwise std::list" Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: sorry i should write multiset, coreected

Comment: the question was about list and multiset @Slava, otherwise I could also referrer to unorder_multiset etc...

Comment: @EduardRostomyan The answer seems to imply that `std::list` is preferred except in the case you mention. This is either misleading or poor advice.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan I doubt somebody would be on choice - choose multiset or list

Comment: refer to the guy who asked the question @Slava

Comment: @EduardRostomyan why? He did not ask "I only have choice multiset or list what do I choose?"

Comment: put on you glasses and read the question description @Slava, call me if you struggle to understand it.

Comment: Yea I get it back, but your answer should say then, there is no really such choice.

Comment: god bless you are here, you can mention that Slavik, @Slava

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few containers in [standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), they have different properties and implication on timing for access, insert and remove elements. You should choose one that is most applicable in particular case from whole group. Your definition of `std::multiset` and `std::list` is artificial and does not make any sense. If chair and horse both have legs it does not mean they are similar.